# Horizontal navbar with float:left;none;right items

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want a horizontal navbar with 3 items: one left, one center, and one right. But I cannot seem to get `float:` to work for me. The attached picture shows how the items do not line up horizontally. I want the centered item to really be a page title, not a link.

The `clear:` I have used seems to at least center the middle item, but without the `clear:` there is no symmetry. How can I get all 3 items to be positioned horizontally?

```
<ul>
  <li style="float:left"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li style="clear:both;float:none"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: Test Navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! You just need to set `text-align: center;` on the parent to center the middle element, then float the first element left and last one right.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li><li><a href="#news">News</a></li><li><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can also have them all take  up the same amount of space and use `text-align` to position the text left/right/center.

```css
ul { padding: 0; }
li {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li><li><a href="#news">News</a></li><li><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your first solution doesn't seem to work for me if I lengthen the center item's text to something like "News of the Day". In that case the middle item is well left of center. Your second solution does not behave well with the longer "News of the Day" because that makes the middle item require 2 lines. I suppose I can play with changing the percentages so that the middle is something like 60% and the others 20%.

Comment: @zerowords it looks fine to me. http://i.imgur.com/56cWbE4.png There is default padding on `ul` that I didn't remove, so that might have made the menu look like it's off center? I updated my answer to remove that. The second solution will cause a link to be on 2 lines if the width of the element becomes > 33.3% of the overall width of the menu, but that's to be expected and you can adapt the widths to be whatever works for you since I don't know your all of your use cases. If you have any more requirements like this, be sure to put them in your OP so we don't waste one another's time.

Comment: @zerowords btw nothing I'm doing requires browser prefixes or has browser support issues like using flexbox. The only thing you might not want to use is `:nth-child()` but it has great browser support, and if you don't want to use that, you can just use CSS classes. I just used `:nth-child()` for the demo because it was quick.

Comment: Yes, I got your first solution to work by removing a CSS command that I had not shown `li { float: left;}`. I'm sorry for the omission. I am next going to try to replace the li and ul and 3 links with the following sequence of 3. Button, Text,  Button because I want the right-most link/button to be disabled until the user completes a complicated "form" which is in several tabs. Instead of changing all that, can you think of a way to apply "disabled" to the right-most link? Or else keeping the ul and li and making the rightmost link's `href="#"`, and maybe altering opacity for disabling.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox does this pretty simply.

Assuming your markup:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

The css will then be:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Do remember to add the necessary vendor prefixes for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Your solution looks simplest until I see your comment about cross-browser compatibility. Does the solution by Michael Coker require adding such vendor prefixes? I am not familiar with vendor prefixes, so this is an issue for me.

Comment: flexbox is supported across all major browsers, but has some issues on IE. (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) If you have a substantial userbase accessing your site on IE, I wouldn't recommend it; otherwise it's pretty much okay. Vendor prefixes are basically additional rules to allow new features to work on browsers while not fully implemented yet. Adding them in ensures the css works the same way on all your browsers. You can use this online tool (http://pleeease.io/play/) to generate vendor prefixes if you're not already adding them during your build. Just paste in your css on the left.

Answer (score 1):

In this issue, you should read [this blog](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) to figure out how to make element horizontal in correct.

In your case, there has servals way to achieve it, I will put them on this answer.

```css
ul {
 padding: 0;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
}

.first li {
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
}

.first .news {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -50px;
 margin-right: -50px;
}

.first li + li + li {
 float: right;
}

.second li {
 display: inline-block;
    float: left;
 width: 33%;
}

.second .news {
 text-align: center;
}

.second li + li + li {
 text-align: right;
    width: 34%;
}

.third {
 position: relative;
}

.third li {
 position: absolute;
}

.third .news {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.third li + li + li {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>1.The key is 'margin-left' nagative value to expand space to text center is right.</h4>
<ul class="first">
  <li>home</li>
  <li class="news">news</li>
  <li>about</li>
</ul>
<br>
<h4>2.The key is make 'li' elements have average width and use text align to achieve it, but there is 1% error, but it's too tiny on sight</h4>
<ul class="second">
  <li>home</li>
  <li class="news">news</li>
  <li>about</li>
</ul>
<h4>3. This situation is easy to understand.</h4>
<ul class="third">
  <li>home</li>
  <li class="news">news</li>
  <li>about</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think I see how I can adapt your approach, especially the third one because you use `width:100%` on the middle item there and that likely would work well with my wider middle items. I am nervous about your first solution because on different screens, I fear that px measurements might not be very versatile.

Comment: @zerowords your worry is right, in this case, I just focus middle second item,If consider different screen and device, there will be have another way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the li inline

```
<li style="display:inline">
```

Comment: No adding `display:inline;` only gives me the same result I had when I left out `clear:both`: The left and middle line up horizontally, but the middle is not centered left to right, and the right item is still below the others.